# How to enable URL MASKING changing HTTP HEADERS

Tags: django, http-headers, url-masking

I have a django application (version 4.0.3) and I want to URL MASK some specific URLs using new purchased domains (in this case GoDaddy)

So what I want to do is:

`www.originaldomain.com/url1` beeing masked with `www.newdomain.com`.
But when I redirect with mask in domain `www.newdomain.com` some HEAERS do not allow it (I know because GoDaddy tech support said me "something is blocking it").

If I do a normal redirect (301 or 302) it works, but not with URL Masking.

I tryied removing `X-Frame-Option: Deny` using a django decorator to the view but still not able to make it work.

Current response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 22 Jul 2022 06:47:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language
Content-Language: es
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=UJp7VSdbT7BnFmc9wKnFZeKSKWjtGbLcEaLEqrZ0MAj8NhU69MDjZQIgWj5LhnWw; expires=Fri, 21 Jul 2023 06:47:40 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie: sessionid=bjtb3e42z9h9wd5tixsw3xpj23kiao1u; expires=Fri, 05 Aug 2022 06:47:40 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
X-Clacks-Overhead: GNU Terry Pratchett
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: PythonAnywhere
```

An explanation of how to find what is blocking it would also be very appreciated (like using